# A way to encode a 3D point with respect to 3 points?

Tags: geometry

I have a point P in 3D which I wasnt to encode with respect to 3 points ABC.

If the point P was on the same plane as the ABC I could use barycentric coordinates.

Is there any standard coordinate system which can encode the point P in terms of ABC? The one I can think of is to use barycentric coordinates plus the distance from the plane to the point.

Are there any other wa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the points as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If they don't lie on a plane through the origin then they will form a basis, and any point can be written uniquely as a linear combination of the three.

Comment: Yes, soon after i wrote the question I realised this! And the barycentric coordinates would just be a special case where coordinates summed to 1. In fact the coordinate of P would int that basis would be $(A.(B\times P),B.(C\times P),C.(A\times P))/A.(B\times C)$

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the vector $PA$ as an algebraic sum of vectors $BA$, $CA$ and $BA\times CA$.